# Циклический сдвиг с условием

Tags: c, массивы

Сделан циклический сдвиг массива влево на 1 элемент. Задание: сдвигать массив, пока значение минимума не станет первым (нулевым значением).

```
void zmischennya(int masuv[], int n, int min, ...)
{
    int j, temp, temp1, k;
    temp = masuv[0];            //запоминаем первый елемент
    printf("\n Zmischennuy masuv na 1:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        masuv[j] = masuv[j + 1];        //сдвигаем на 1 елемент
        masuv[n] = temp;
        printf("\t %i", masuv[j]);
    }
    printf("\n Zmischenuy masuv min=1:\n");
    temp1 = masuv[0];
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)     //цыкл смещения пока мин == масив[0]
    {
        if (masuv[0] != min)    // проверка не стоит ли мин первым, если нет то: 
        {                       // сдвигаем пока не выполниться условие
            masuv[j] = masuv[j + 1];
            masuv[n] = temp1;
            printf("\t %i", masuv[j]);
        } else                  // если да то просто выводим значения
            printf("\t %i", masuv[j]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Но работает только сдвиг влево, а сдвиг, пока не выполнится условие, не работает. Почему? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Найдите индекс минимального элемента и сдвиньте массив на эту величину.

Кстати, писали Вам, писали в предыдущем вопросе, как надо делать циклический сдвиг, а в программе все равно он с ошибкой.

Прежде всего подумайте над masuv[n] = temp;
 У Вас сколько элементов в masuv?

Comment: Обратите внимание: возвращать сохранённое во временной переменной значение надо лишь один раз. И оно должно попасть в элемент с макс. индексом -- но это индекс `n-1`, а не `n`!

Comment: 1. Минимум, поди, искать надо, а Вы для легкой жизни его в параметры загнали.
2. Откажитесь от привычки писать тексты на "воляпюке", типа masuv. Отвратительное впечатление призводит на читателя и на препода тоже подействует плохо.